# Windows 10 Enterprise version 1709 - cannot edit or remove Start Menu tiles

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-10-v1709

My computer here at work was just upgraded to Windows 10 version 1709 (Fall Creators Update), build 16299.125.  The Windows Start Menu now contains tiles for Weather, Mail, 3D Paint, OneNote, XBox, etc.  In previous versions of Windows 10, I could right click on these tiles and remove them, or drag and rearrange them.  Now, my only options are to "Turn Live tile off," "Pin to Taskbar," "Rate and Review" and "Share."

I have run gpresult and confirmed that the Group Policy for User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Start Layout is Disabled (At first it was "Not Configured," so I disabled it).  But I still cannot edit, delete or customize any of the Start Menu tiles in this Fall Creators Update.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If this work computer is on a domain, you should start by asking your local IT. They may have either set a policy (Group Policy is not the only place policy can be defined for Windows systems) or this may be a problem they need to be aware of to fix.

Comment: *"My computer here at work..."*  This is really the key.  Your `Local Group Policy Editor` will not necessarily show the effects of a domain-level GPO.  Beyond that, there are other configurations that can affect what you see on the Start Menu.  We are always glad to help, but you really need to consult your Domain Admin support staff.

Comment: @Run5k I thought gpresult would show me what policies were being imposed upon my computer by the domain GPO.  gpresult is not showing that anything is coming down for the Start Layout policy.  And yes, I am working with my domain admins on this too.  I'll update here if I find out anything.  Thanks.

Comment: Reporting back on some things that *didn't* work: rebuilt my user profile.  Replaced the c:\users\default profile with one from a non-problematic Win10 1709 installation (then rebuilt my user profile again).  I'm starting to think only a clean install will fix this...